SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions Fails With "Invalid Window", Any Ideas?
I've been trying to solve this problem and I've been drawing a blank.  Below is the script I have been trying to run with no success.  All that happens for me is I run the program, the script initializes SDL3, loads the default library, creates a window, then queries the necessary extensions.  Upon running SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(...), I get the error "Invalid Window" from SDL_GetError().  I'm creating the window with SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN, but it's not working. I've debugged and the window is not NULL, it does appear on the screen.  However, I can't do anything to fix this.  Leaving the header files I'm using in because I don't know if that might be interfering with the process.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vulkan/vulkan.h>
#include <cglm/cglm.h>
#include <vk_mem_alloc.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <SDL3/SDL.h>
#include <SDL3/SDL_vulkan.h>

typedef struct Window_T {
    SDL_Window* window;
    VkExtent2D size;
    char* name;
    VkSurfaceKHR surface;
} Window;


int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    printf("ERROR INIT: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    SDL_Vulkan_LoadLibrary(NULL);
    printf("ERROR LOAD: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    Window window;
    //createWindow(&window, 800, 600, "Hello from SDL3");
    window.window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello, SDL3!", 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);
    printf("ERROR MAKE: %s\n", SDL_GetError());

    Uint32 sdl_required_extension_count;
    const char* const* sdl_required_extensions = SDL_Vulkan_GetInstanceExtensions(&sdl_required_extension_count);

    printf("SDL_REQUIRED_EXTENSION_COUNT: %d\n", sdl_required_extension_count);
    printf("ERROR: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window.window);

    return 0;
}

I've tried printf debugging, SDL_GetError(), checking the linker, reading the documentation, but nothing seems to be showing the solution. If anyone can help I would be very grateful!

I've tried to replicate your code using SDL preview-3.1.6 and both the extension number and the required extensions get reported correctly. The steps I followed are:

git clone https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL.git SDL
Open and build SDL/VisualC/SDL.sln
Create a new project with your code
Add an include directory that points to SDL/include.
Add a linker path to SDL/VisualC/x64/Debug
Copy SDL/VisualC/x64/Debug/SDL3.dll into the same folder as the exe.


If after following these steps you get the same error you need to check that you have a good Vulkan installation and that you are linking correctly with SDL.
First thing I would try is to check that the demos in the Vulkan SDK work. You can find them at %VULKAN_SDK%/Demos.
After that I would test a basic triangle sample you can find online. For example:

git clone --recursive https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan.git
cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019" -A x64
Then set the Triangle demo as the default project, then build and run it

If the Vulkan Demos or the Triangle Example work it means you have a problem with SDL. Check that you are linking with the correct lib/dll or try with SDL2.

To make tesing easier you can use this batch file:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:compile
    set      prjName=Sandbox
    set        files=%~dp0\src\main.cpp
    set     buildDir=%~dp0\build\Win-x64-%target%\%prjName%\
    set  buildIntDir=%~dp0\build-int\Win-x64-%target%\%prjName%\
    set   exceptions=-EHa-
    set    subsystem=-subsystem:console

    echo Building %prjName% for %target%...

    set compilerFlags=^
        -Fe%prjName% ^
        -Fo%buildIntDir% ^
        -diagnostics:column ^
        -Oi -Gm- -GR- %exceptions% -FC -nologo -std:c++17 ^
        -fp:fast -fp:except- ^
        -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 ^
        -I %~dp0\src ^
        -I%VULKAN_SDK%\Include ^
        -IC:\dev\SDL\include

    set   debugCompilerFlags=-MDd -Zo -Zi
    set releaseCompilerFlags=-MD -GL -O2
    set          linkerFlags=-WX -opt:ref -incremental:no %subsystem% -LIBPATH:C:\dev\SDL\VisualC\x64\Debug
    
    :: Create Build directories and copy resources.res
    if not exist %buildDir% mkdir %buildDir%
    if not exist %buildIntDir% mkdir %buildIntDir%
    
    pushd %buildDir%
        del %prjName%.pdb > NUL 2> NUL
        del %prjName%.* > NUL 2> NUL

        cl %compilerFlags% %debugCompilerFlags% %files% /link %linkerFlags% SDL3.lib
    popd

    goto :exit

:exit
    exit /B !ERRORLEVEL!

With this folder structure:


build.bat
[src]

main.cpp


[build]
[build-int]


Call build.bat and the copy SDL/VisualC/x64/Debug/SDL3.dll in build/Win-x64-Debug/Sandbox. Afther that you can open the exe in Visual Studio or your debugger of choice and test it.

So, you were right about the issue being in the Linker settings. While  I looked around most of my files and what I was doing, I kept checking your checklist you provided.  I knew that the SDL2/Vulkan demos would work since I had used these APIs in the past.  The issue was much simpler, I was linking against -l SDL2 instead of -l SDL3.  Thank you for helping me find where I was going wrong with my code!
